# Unique key prop is not accepted. How can i make it work?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I´m trying to give my form to a new page. Problem is that they unique id is not being accepted and i can´t figure out why.

Form code:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useLocalStorage } from "react-use";
import useLocalStorageState from "use-local-storage-state";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import AnimalDetails from "./AnimalDetails";

export default function AddAnimalForm() {
  const [animalData, setAnimalData] = useLocalStorage("Animal Data", []);
  const [animals, setAnimals] = useLocalStorageState("animals", []);
  const [submitMessage, setSubmitMessage] = useState(false);
  const [showDetails, setShowDetails] = useState(false);

  const { register, handleSubmit, formState: { errors } } = useForm();

  const onSubmit = (data, event) => {
    event.target.reset();
    const id = uuidv4();
    const newAnimalData = { ...data, id: id };
    setAnimalData([...animalData, newAnimalData]);
    setAnimals([...animals, newAnimalData]);
    setSubmitMessage(true);
    setShowDetails(true);
    setTimeout(() => {
      setSubmitMessage(false);
      setShowDetails(false);
    }, 3000);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <select {...register("species", { required: true })}>
          <option value="">--Choose Animal--</option>
          <option value="dog">Dog</option>
          <option value="cat">Cat</option>
          <option value="rabbit">Rabbit</option>
          <option value="tortoise">Tortoise</option>
          <option value="guinea pig">Guinea pig</option>
        </select>
        {errors.species && <span>Species is required</span>}
        <ul>
          <input {...register("name", { required: true })} key="name" placeholder="Name" />
          {errors.name && <span>Name is required</span>}
          <input {...register("age", { required: true })} key="age" placeholder="Age" />
          {errors.age && <span>Age is required</span>}
          <input {...register("character", { required: true })} key="character" placeholder="Character" />
          {errors.character && <span>Character is required</span>}
          <input {...register("owner", { required: true })} key="owner" placeholder="Owners" />
          {errors.owner && <span>Owners is required</span>}
          <input {...register("miscellaneous")} key="miscellaneous" placeholder="miscelleaneous" />
        </ul>
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
      {submitMessage && <p>Form submitted successfully</p>}
      {showDetails && <AnimalDetails animals={animals} />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Details Page code that should render all input infos:

```
import React from "react";

export default function AnimalDetails({ animals }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Animal Details</h2>
      {animals.map((animal) => (
        <div key={animal.id}>
          <p>Species: {animal.species}</p>
          <p>Name:{animal.name}</p>
          <p>Age: {animal.age}</p>
          <p>Character: {animal.character}</p>
          <p>Owner: {animal.owner}</p>
          <p>Miscellaneous: {animal.miscellaneous}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I thought giving my div a key element would be enough but after that i got the following error:

Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.

Comment: Most likely your id is not unique or it's a different list that throws the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{animals.map((animal, index) => (
  <div key={index}>
    <p>Species: {animal.species}</p>
    <p>Name:{animal.name}</p>
    <p>Age: {animal.age}</p>
    <p>Character: {animal.character}</p>
    <p>Owner: {animal.owner}</p>
    <p>Miscellaneous: {animal.miscellaneous}</p>
  </div>
))}
```